# Finding list of all duplicates based on calculated value

Tags: php, mysql

Using MySQL, I am trying to get a list of ONLY the teams that are tied (has the same number of wins) from a list of all teams in a given list. To calculate the wins for each team, I am using a SUM function while grouping by teams.

So far I have created this query:

```
SELECT results.DATE, 
    results.team1, 
    SUM(results.win) AS WINS, 
    SUM(results.lose) AS LOSSES, 
    SUM(results.pt_diff) AS PT_DIFF, 
    event_team.div_sname, 
    event_team.pool_name 
FROM results, 
    event_team, 
    matches
WHERE results.team1 = event_team.team_id
    AND results.sched_id = matches.sched_id
    AND matches.match_type = 'pool'
    AND event_team.div_sname = 'C4A'
    AND event_team.pool_name = 'Pool_C4A_1'
    AND event_team.event_id = 25
GROUP BY results.team1
ORDER BY event_team.pool_name, wins DESC, losses ASC, PT_DIFF DESC
```

This query returns the entire list of teams and their

```
DATE         team1  WINS    LOSSES  PT_DIFF  div_sname  pool_name   
----------  ------  ------  ------  -------  ---------  ------------
2014-09-06      54  9       3       28       C4A        Pool_C4A_1  
2014-09-06      62  6       6       -2       C4A        Pool_C4A_1  
2014-09-06      55  5       7       1        C4A        Pool_C4A_1  
2014-09-06      59  5       7       -7       C4A        Pool_C4A_1  
2014-09-06      65  5       7       -20      C4A        Pool_C4A_1
```

How do I eliminate the first two rows in the example above so that I only get team 55, 59, and 65 who are all tied with 5 wins each? Please note that I may have multiple ties in my overall results so any solution must capture all teams with ties even if the wins are different between the groups.

I have tried the following but after further reading it seems I can not GROUP BY an aggregate function. How else can I approach this?

```
SELECT results.DATE, 
    results.team1, 
    SUM(results.win) AS WINS, 
    event_team.div_sname, 
    event_team.pool_name
FROM results, 
     event_team, 
     matches
WHERE results.team1 = event_team.team_id
    AND results.sched_id = matches.sched_id
    AND matches.match_type = 'pool'
    AND event_team.div_sname = 'C4A'
    AND event_team.pool_name = 'Pool_C4A_1'
    AND event_team.event_id = 25
GROUP BY WINS
HAVING COUNT(WINS) >1
```

Thanks in advance for any and all replies!

Comment: So, this example isn't really representative of the problem that hand? Well, that's useful.

Comment: The question seems like you are looking for a MySQL-only solution, but it's also tagged as PHP. Are you open to PHP solutions?

Comment: Yes. The question I have posed is one of a larger problem of trying to rank teams based on Wins and Losses as well as building in logic to break ties. First I am trying to identify the teams with ties before working on logic (code) to break the tie and rerank the teams accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
SELECT
    results.DATE, 
    results.team1, 
    results.win, 
    event_team.div_sname, 
    event_team.pool_name
FROM results, 
     event_team, 
     matches
WHERE results.team1 = event_team.team_id
    AND results.sched_id = matches.sched_id
    AND matches.match_type = 'pool'
    AND event_team.div_sname = 'C4A'
    AND event_team.pool_name = 'Pool_C4A_1'
    AND event_team.event_id = 25

    AND results.win IN (SELECT results.win FROM results GROUP BY results.win HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

This will give you a result set that looks like this:

```
+------------+-------+-----+-----------+------------+
| DATE       | team1 | win | div_sname | pool_name  |
+------------+-------+-----+-----------+------------+
| 2014-09-06 |    55 | 5   | C4A       | Pool_C4A_1 |
| 2014-09-06 |    59 | 5   | C4A       | Pool_C4A_1 |
| 2014-09-06 |    65 | 5   | C4A       | Pool_C4A_1 |
+------------+-------+-----+-----------+------------+
```

That subquery just selects all the numbers of wins where there is more than one row having that number of wins.

Comment: thanks for the speedy reply. Unfortunately, this does not work. Wins is a calculated field. Each game is stored in the results table as a win for one team and a loss for another. The subquery is returning all teams where a win is either 0 or 1. This is getting to the root of my problem in that I am not sure how to work with the "SUM" function I am using to calculate the overall wins.